# iOS Local Notification Sound Not Working

Tags: ios, audio, notifications, local

I'm using a UILocalNotification to inform a user about some events. The problem is, if I choose a custom sound for that, the system's default sound is played nonetheless. The weird thing about that is that sometimes it still works with my sound and sometimes it doesn't. I have properly adressed the file and converted it into a correct caf format. 
When I reboot the device it works perfectly. So why does my sound play some times and other times the system default Sound?

Answer (score 0):

your notification sounds may not be longer than 30 seconds - if the file supplied is longer, nothing will sound.

Also,check the sound in some external player first, and best convert it to .caf format.

To convert a file to .caf, open up terminal, go to where you have your sound stored and type in:

afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 yourfile.wav yourfile.caf
Then just set it like:

```
yourNotification.soundName = @"yoursound_name.caf";
```

Comment: As I already said, my files ARE in correct format and as they sometimes work they are shorter than 30 seconds as well. I wanted to know why I have to reboot my device in order to get these sounds to work.